# How are phosphorescent displays used as monitors?

Tags: laser

I've recently been looking into old displays such as the ones on the [tektronix 4010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tektronix_4010). These displays "draw" on a phosphorescent screen in a way that is really fascinating, and I want to recreate it. My goal is to use an Arduino controlled blue laser and glow in the dark paint to mimic one of these proto-crts.

There are a few abilities of the tektronix displays which I don't fully understand though. The first is the ability to clear the phosphorescent panel simply by emitting a short flash. As far as I know this should just flood the screen, not clear it. The wiki page on [storage tubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storage_tube) says that in order to make the panel light up you excite it with energy above a certain threshold and then to "erase" it energy is applied above a second threshold. Practically speaking, does this just mean that I can flash a bright bulb at my makeshift screen and have it clear (I find this unlikely) or is this some flaw in my setup.

Secondly, how are these displays so readable even in daylight as well as having very long persistance with almost no noticable fade? Is this just some very powerful phosphor or is there something else? It doesn't seem from any of the videos I've seen that the displays are refreshing at all, though I do wonder what you would see if you killed the power. Anyway, can someone more knowlegable, maybe even with experince with such display shed some light?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. You have a bit of a wall of text there. Use <Enter> x 2 to break it up into paragraphs. You also have a number of questions. If you use the numbered list button (insert a blank line first) for each individual question it makes it easier for those responding.

Comment: Thanks for the input I'll keep that in mind when posting future questions, I've broken it up a bit.

Comment: Why do you assume that glow-in-the-dark paint works the same way as a storage CRT does?

Comment: http://ecomputernotes.com/computer-graphics/graphics-device/write-short-note-on-direct-view-storage-tube

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storage CRT's are a different thing.

The ongoing storage glow is continually powered by electrons - it is not some property of the phosphorescent material itself. So outside of a storage vacuum tube, the material is just ordinary phosphor and has no special "erase" property.

With a phosphorescent material, you just need to keep re-writing the image with your laser. This is entirely doable, and should be wickedly good.

You do need to use vector (line) graphics not raster scan type images.